# Display actual values instead of coordinates when using ggplotly in combination with ggradar

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, radar-chart

I use `ggradar` in combination with `plotly` to create a radar chart. After using `plotly` to obtain the hover-text ability I get the coordinates of every point when I mouse over each point but this does not make sense to me. How can I get the actual values instead of coordinates?

```
library(ggradar)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(tibble)
library(plotly)
mtcars_radar <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "group") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-group), rescale) %>% 
  tail(4) %>% 
  select(1:10)

p<-ggradar(mtcars_radar)
ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: not sure it is possible. when you look at the `p` object, the actual values are no longer available. the only solution I can see is to create multiple layers as explained in https://plot.ly/r/radar-chart/#multiple-trace-radar-charts, but it is much more cumbersome.